# Deleting observations without a observation in a consecutive year

Tags: r

I want to delete observations that does not have a consecutive year.
This would also be all last observations.

```
dput(head(df)) 
structure(list(ID = c(13302, 13302, 14401, 14401, 14401, 14401 ), 
               Jaar = c(2012, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016))
```

In this example, both observations of `ID 13302` would be deleted and of `ID 14401` observation of `2013` and `2016` should be deleted.

Can anyone assist with the code for this in R? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little shorter:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[,ind:=c(diff(Jaar),NA),by="ID"][ind %in% 1,]
```

#### Output

```
      ID Jaar ind
1: 14401 2012   1
2: 14401 2015   1
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(ID = c(13302, 13302, 14401, 14401, 14401, 14401), Jaar = c(2012, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016))
df[, diff := shift(Jaar, type = 'lead'), by = 'ID'][, diff := diff - Jaar]
df[, id := rleid(diff)]
df[diff == 1][, head(.SD, n = 1), by = 'id'][, .(ID, Jaar)]
```

output

```
     ID Jaar
1: 14401 2012
2: 14401 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another data.table approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[, Jaar+1 == shift(Jaar, type = "lead"), by = ID]$V1]
#      ID Jaar
#1: 14401 2012
#2: 14401 2015
```

Comment: the same question as above.

Comment: @myincas, Not sure what your comment means. If there are more continuous years in one ID then it is supposed to get all the consecutive years except the last one.. And I guess this is what my code does.